# How to develop and distribute iOS apps without macOS?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter but I don't have a macOS and iPhone. Can I use rent a mac for developing and debugging iOS apps in XCode simulator or can I check push notification on iOS simulator.

Comment: You can use rent a Mac or a CI tool with Xcode support; Essentially you need the Xcode toolchain to build an app for delivery to the App Store.  You will find it difficult to develop and test without the ability to run on an iOS simulator at the very least and preferably a real device.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop an ios app without macOS, but can't build IPA

Comment: i think this is wrong, you _can_ develop for ios without a mac. you can't distribute what you'll be making though

Comment: so then your answer is wrong? you can develop for it (using flutter or pehaps another cross platform framework), but you can't build, so that's the difference

Comment: when you developed but can't build IPA that is not useful